# looping through results_array() gives error: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a ci / bonfire application.  I'm trying to loop through results of a query.  However, the logic in my view that loops through the records and their individual fields fails with the message that I'm trying to get a property of a non-object.
I've made sure that in my model, I only return data if I have something to return... like so:

```
       if ($query->num_rows() > 0) 
        { 
            return $query->result_array(); //returns an object of data
        }
```

In the view, I've also added the following debug statement to prove that I'm getting data back:

```
  print_r($records);
```

That gives me the following output: (I've only included a subset to be brief..)

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [category_id] => 59 [name] => procs [description] => [parent_id] => 4 [deleted] => 0 [created_on] => 2012-09-28 00:00:00 [modified_on] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00 ) [1] => Array ( [category_id] => 62 [name] => test [description] => [parent_id] => 4 [deleted] => 0 [created_on] => 2012-09-28 00:00:00 [modified_on] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00 )
```

And finally, here's the logic (again, only subset) I use to loop through $records:

```
  <?php foreach ($records as $record) : ?>
   <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checked[]" value="<?php echo $record->category_id ?>" /></td>
```

It's dying on the call to `$record->category_id`

**EDIT 1**

The index() method my controller that bonfire created to return all records from the same table, successfully uses the syntax `$record->category_id` in the view.  I know that I can use `$record['category_id']` but I'm wondering why I can't get it to work the other way.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: try $record['category_id'] instead of $record->category_id

Comment: if you want to use objects, then you should supply ->result() instead of ->result_array()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you are getting an object (the print_r would have been different otherwise).
That said, the 'foreach' method is used for array traversal, not object, even if a object is supplied to the 'foreach' loop, it is converted to equivalent associative array, so, in your case '$record' is no longer an object, but an associative array.

Answer (score 2):

use

```
$record['category_id ']
```

Should do the trick,
Wezy

Comment: hey there.  yeah... that works. but what i'm wondering is why the other way won't.  i'm actually using bonfire with code igniter and the index() method my controller that bonfire created to return all records successfully uses the syntax $record->category_id.  I will update my post to include this information

Comment: @dot - because the other way is used with class objects not arrays

Comment: If you wanted an object you would return $query->result() not result_array()